# kotlin execute code upon coroutine return

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

Newbie question with coroutines :-)

With coroutines that doesn't return a value, is there a way to execute some code upon the completion of that coroutine ?

In this example, `funcA()` performs some async call and upon completion `funcB`, `funcC` needs to complete, the rest of the code can continue to execute independent of `funcA()` completion

```
... other code executing
... other code executing

launch {
  funcA()
}
funcB()
funcC()

... other code executing
... other code executing
```

One approach would be to enclose `funcB`, `funcC` within a method and we can use async with await ... but why return a value just for that.

i.e.

```
executeFunBC()
{
  funcB()
  funcC()
}


launch {
 val result = funcA()
}
 executeFunBC(result).await()
```

Basically, in some languages you can use 'blocks' or closures and execute some code upon completion of that block in the same method. (similar to callbacks)

Back to my question:

Is there a way to define the execution of `funcB`, `funcC` upon the completion of `funcA()` in the same function ?

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple, just do this:

```
launch {
  funcA()

  // Will not execute until funcA() returns
  funcB() 
  funcC()
}
```

but make sure you use a dispatcher that works for `funcB()` and `funcC()`, e.g. like this `launch(Dispatchers.Main) {`.